# What AI technologies were used in earlier versions of StarCraft?

Tags: game-ai, reference-request

I remember back in the 2000s, it was, and still is possible to play against computers in StarCraft BroodWar. They were not as good as pro players, but still reasonably smart.

What AI technologies were used in earlier versions of StarCraft: Brood War?

Comment: See [https://github.com/bwapi/bwapi](https://github.com/bwapi/bwapi) and [https://github.com/jncraton/BWMetaAI](https://github.com/jncraton/BWMetaAI), which may be useful, although I think they are related to recent versions of the game. See also [http://www.cs.mun.ca/~dchurchill/starcraftaicomp/history.shtml](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~dchurchill/starcraftaicomp/history.shtml) and https://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/300931/Without_code_from_the_original_Blizzard_had_to_build_StarCraft_Remastered_from_scratch.php.

Comment: @nbro the links are good for an answer.

Comment: Ok, maybe later I will provide one or you can provide one for yourself and I will upvote it if you provide details about the AI in the game ;)

Comment: But are you only interested in the AIs used in the old versions of the game? I only quickly skimmed through those links, but I don't think they provide any info about the AIs used in those old games. If you are interested in an overview of the AIs used also in current and more recent versions, then the links above should definitely be useful.

Comment: Overview will do fine.